# drag-drop not found in @angular/cdk

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, angular-material, angular-cdk, angular-dragdrop

i am trying to add the drag-drop feature in my Angular 6 application
where i am trying to use angular material
[this is the overview link](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview) which i want to use. I followed the [getting started](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started) instruction's but i am not able to use the "@angular/cdk/drag-drop" 
i tried installing the bellow package

> npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk @angular/animations

and

> npm install --save @angular/cdk

but the bellow folder is still missing 
[image]

> import {DragDropModule} from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';

the drag-drop is not available in my project even after following the steps. can anyone help me with that

Comment: It looks like all you need to do is close and reopen your IDE. If you're using VS Code, press the F1 key, then choose *Developer: Reload Window* from the dropdown.

Comment: hi @R.Richards thank you very much for the response but I am still facing the same problem after trying your solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`@angular/cdk/drag-drop` exists only from version 7.0.0 of `@angular/cdk`. It seems you have to update angular and cdk to use drag-drop

Comment: thank you @Andrei for your solution but is there any other solution where I do not requires to update the Angular project

Comment: If you want the exact @angular/cdk/drag-drop library then no, you have to upgrage. If no then you can use some other drag-and-drop library. the most popular for angular is [ng2-dragula](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-dragula)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. Try:
ng add @angular/material

Answer (score 0):

Try this npm install @angular/cdk

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34539349)